# Random binary tree search time comparison, same duration for different tree hight's

Tags: c, performance, binary-tree, binary-search-tree

I'm comparing graphs about the time it takes for a random key search in different size binary trees, that are not ordered. The amount of times i call the function that search's a key value in a tree is fixed at 1024 times, i only change the amount of elements in a tree, from 2^6 elements, 2^8, and so on until 2^14. The problem is i keep getting the same results for the duration of the search, with slighty difference, for all the trees sizes, the way im calculation the time is

```
init = clock();
for (i = 0; i < 1024; i++) {
    //key is randomly generated in the same range of the elements in the tree
    search(&key, &tree);
}
end = clock();
//Getting time in usec.
time = (double) 1000000 * (end - init) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
```

Comment: is this your *actual* code and `search()` is defined in the same translation unit? Is `search()` defined to return what was found? If so, your compiler might just decide that the call to `search()` has no observable behavior whatsoever and therefore throws it out.

Comment: Are you sure the trees are not ordered?  Can you post the logic that builds the tree? If your tree is in fact ordered (being then a binary-search tree that you are tagging in your question) and happens to be nicely balanced then the similar search duration is expected, being an O(log n) operation on average

Comment: And 1024 repeats is ridiculously small. Keep increasing it until you get to at least a second or two.